# Capybara escaping regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm trying to write a test in a Rails application using Capybara that includes this:

```
expect(page).to have_content(text: /\bEdit\b/)
```

I need the word boundaries on the string because other content on the page will match without it (for example, the word "Editorial").

When I run that, I get a failure with the following message:

```
expected to find text "{:text=>/\\bEdit\\b/}" ...
```

Note the double escaping on the `\b`'s!

**How do tell Capybara not to escape my backslashes in my regex?**

Answer (score 2):

Capybara's `have_content` (alias of `have_text`) takes a string or a regexp - not a :text option.
You want

```
expect(page).to have_content(/\bEdit\b/)
```

Note: current versions of Capybara should have raised an error telling you that :text was not a valid option for the `have_content` matcher, so I'm not sure how old a version of Capybara you are running.